# Rails undefined method errors showing on session controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clearance

I am building an application in which I am trying to login using clearance.I have build login and sign up page .They are working very smooth but the problem is when I am trying to show error when user enters any wrong email or password so my **<% if :session.errors.any? %>** is not working .It is saying **undefined method `errors' for :session:Symbol**

[Session_controller]

```
class SessionController < ApplicationController

    def new
    end

    def create
        @session = authenticate(params)
        sign_in(@session) do |status|
            if status.success?      
                redirect_to root_path
            else
                render 'new'    
            end
        end
    end

    private
          def user_params
            params.require(:session).permit(:email,:password)
          end
end
```

[session/_form.html.erb]

Answer (score 1):

You are calling errors on `:session`, which is a symbol. 
You may want to try calling errors on `@session`.

Comment: You mean the error is still `undefined method 'errors' for :session:Symbol `?

Comment: no error is different it is undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

Comment: which means `authenticate(params)` is returning nil, which is being assigned to `@session`. You may want to check the inner workings of `authenticate` or provide the implementation for further review.

Comment: Okay I am checking and updating my answer

Comment: I have check my authenticate(params) method it is not returning me nil.It is giving me the whole data when i do puts"#{@session.to_json}"

Comment: If in the controller `@session` is giving you data, but it is being `nil` in your view, the only explanation is that there could be a typo in the variable name in the view.

Comment: well you can see my code and i don't thing there is typo .I have already have session controller and _form.html.erb in my question

Comment: If you could include the details of `authenticate` , `sign_in` and the _form.html.erb, that might give some insight.

Answer (score 0):

> undefined method `errors' for :session:Symbol

[**`errors`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validations-overview-errors) should be called on a new model instance i.e, `Model.new`. You should have `@session` defined as `Session.new` in `new` method, the below should work

```
#session_controller
def new
  @session = Session.new
end

#in the view
<% if @session.errors.any? %>
```

Comment: you can see my controller I have not defined anything in my new method of  session controller . Because when i do so it is showing error uninitialized constant SessionController::Session

Comment: @aniket Normally you should be having the Session model too.. Which tutorial you are following?

Comment: I don't have session model .I am not following any tutorial